# How to open hyperlinks in excel without mouse-click; is there any shortcut key/Keys

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have many hyperlinks in a column of excel-sheet.

Is/Are there any shortcut key/Keys so that after going to each cell(using keyboard) I can open those in browser without using mouse-click?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Excel 2016 (English version), I would say that the simplest way to do this is to

- press the <kbd>menu</kbd> key (that has a similar effect to a right click)
- press <kbd>o</kbd> twice
- press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The first <kbd>o</kbd> goes to "sort" ; the second <kbd>o</kbd> goes to "Open Hyperlink", and "Enter" then opens the hyperlink.

On a keyboard that does not have a <kbd>menu</kbd> key, one can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> instead.

[image: menu key]

[image: Excel menu with open hyperlink selected]

Comment: Points for Google Sheets and their ALT+ENTER here

Comment: Works great, but unfortunately it clears clipboard, which doesn't happen when the link is clicked with mouse or touchpad buttons.

Comment: Menu key and right click is not the same. [Especially not for Win11](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/right-click-menu-windows-11/). Also this duplicates [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41216696/4575793).

Comment: The info with `shift`+`F10` was good!

Answer (score 6):

Press the <kbd>menu</kbd> key and then press <kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>o</kbd>.

[More about Menu Key here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key).

Comment: In Excel 2013, this only opens the `Sort` menu. Any other ideas?

Comment: My Excel is not in English and I have no idea which other shortcut to use, because there is not a single item in the popup menu that would activate the hyperlink.

Comment: @AndrewRalon Press "o" twice...should take you to the "Open Hyperlink" option at the bottom of the menu.

Comment: @interDist I'm not sure what it would be in something besides English, but when I have a cell with a hyperlink selected, the very  bottom option in the menu is "Open Hyperlink".

Comment: The answer by @Alexandre d'Entraigues below shows it in pictures. Excellent.

Answer (score 6):

To open a hyperlinked file in excel, try the following

1. Select the cell.
2. Press <kbd>application</kbd> key (<kbd>menu</kbd> key).
3. Press <kbd>O</kbd> key twice.
4. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 5):

Create a macro with the following.  The cell with the link should only include text of the hyperlink (and not use the Excel function hyperlink with an embedded link).  Note that the "... chrome.exe " has a [space] between exe and quote (").

```
Sub ClickHyperlnk()
'
' ClickHyperlnk Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'

With Selection.Interior
    URL = ActiveCell.Value
    Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe " & URL, vbNormalNoFocus

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub hyhperlink()
'
' hyhperlink Macro
' opens hyperlink
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+X
'
With Selection.Interior
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End With

End Sub
```

or **record a macro for this operation**

Comment: How would you record a macro?

Answer (score 3):

Go in excel view tab

1. Click on micro
2. Click Record micro
3. type text in shortcut key i.e.(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>q</kbd>)
4. enter OK
5. Press the <kbd>menu</kbd> key and then press <kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>o</kbd> in excel Where is your hyper link data & <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. again go in view > micro > click on stop micro

Now you can use your short cut key i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>q</kbd> for hyperlink cells in excel

Comment: There is a difference between `ctrl`+`q` and `ctrl`+`shift`+`q`

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post but maybe it could help someone searching for this shortcut. To open a link without going through "Edit Links" follow these couple of steps:

- click on a cell that is linked to another file
- then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

This will open the linked file.

Comment: The question title says "without clicking"

Answer (score 1):

I found out this command doesn't work for me with the <kbd>o</kbd> twice, maybe because I have a column of hyperlinks.

What I do is:

1. Select cell
2. <kbd>Menu</kbd> key
3. **<kbd>Up_Arrow</kbd>**
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Opening the link is the last proposition of the menu, so going <kbd>up</kbd> goes to the last option. Pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> activates it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make keyboard shortcut for hyperlinks formula / function.

Just press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> copy and paste the script below:

```
Sub OpenHyp()
Workbooks.Open "FOLDER ADDRESS\" & ActiveCell.Value & "FILE EXTENSION"
End Sub
```

`replace the FOLDER ADDRESS` = you can find it on address bar of the file location just copy, paste and add "" at the end of file address.

`no need to replace ActiveCell.Value` = this is the filename of your file which is usually the content of cell.

`replace the FILEEXTENSION` = for pdf used ".pdf", for normal excel file used ".xlsx" and so on.

Then, go to developer tab, click Macros, select the code we make which is "OpenHyp" and click "Option". Now you can put the shortcut key.