# How can I open Excel 2010 hyperlinks with the keyboard?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to Google search a term. So, I did a concatenate formula that creates a hyperlink. It looks something like:

=CONCATENATE("https://www.google.com/search?q=",A1)

Where A1 is the location of the term I want to search.

So far, so good. This gives me a hyperlink in text form. Then, I create a second column to establish the actual hyperlink:

=HYPERLINK(location of the concatenate formula result)

Great. I've got a working hyperlink. If I use the mouse to click that formula, it opens the Google search correctly.

Now, I want to use the keyboard instead of my mouse to click this hyperlink. I need to do a bunch of these types of searches. Maybe I'll create a macro that can open them for me a few at a time.

Anyway, this [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188425/how-to-open-hyperlinks-in-excel-without-mouse-click-is-there-any-shortcut-key-k) describes a way of opening hyperlinks in Excel without using the mouse. The problem I have is that I don't see "Open Hyperlink" in my context menu. All I've got is "Remove Hyperlink".

Any ideas why and what I can do to work around it? Thanks!